# Meteor: Share Template

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, npm, meteor-blaze

I'm building an app using Meteor with a really large form. I'm using almost the same html template twice, once for input and once for output, but the helpers are different.

As two templates are hard to maintain, my question is, if there is a way to share a html template or clone it, so that I can have the same template but different helpers and events?

Comment: Look for the community packages for forms, they might simplify this task a lot: https://atmospherejs.com/aldeed/autoform

Comment: I've looked at it, sadly it doesn't help in this case. But thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a template argument for this purpose.

HTML

```
<template name="parent">
  {{> reusableTemplate mode="input"}}
  {{> reusableTemplate mode="output"}}
</template>
```

`client/views/reusable-template/reusable-template.html`

```
<template name="reusableTemplate">
  <form>
    <p>{{helper}}</p>
    <button type="submit">
      Submit
    </button>
  </form>
</template>
```

JS

`client/views/reusable-template/lib/input.js`

```
inputHelper=function (){
  console.log(this.mode);
  // specific input code
};
```

`client/views/reusable-template/lib/output.js`

```
outputHelper=function(){
  console.log(this.mode);
  // specific output code
};
```

`client/views/reusable-template/reusable-template.js`

```
Template.reusableTemplate.helpers({
  helper:function(){
    if(this.mode == "input"){
      inputHelper.call(this);
    }
    else{
      outputHelper.call(this);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks good! However, it will blow my code, as I have to merge two helper functions into one, same for the rendered method /: Any idea on that?

Comment: EDIT : Refactored the code and file organization to a tidier proposal, is that what you had in mind ?